# Creating an Alpha Overlay Image from the Difference of Two Images

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, python-imaging-library

I've been having a weirdly difficult time with this problem. I have two images, we'll call them base

[image]

and light

[image]

(the actual images are much higher resolution, but the issue should be the same regardless). My goal is to produce a new image, we'll call it `alpha` which, when overlaid on `base` produces `light`. I've tried doing all sorts of difference/subtraction, scaling, brightness adjustments, etc, but nothing I do seems to actually produce the result (often it looks close, but never exact).

For example, this code is about as close as I've gotten without using image editing software to guess-and-check it closer.

```
from PIL import Image, ImageEnhance
import numpy
import blend_modes
import sys
import scipy


background_img_raw = Image.open(sys.argv[1])
background_img_raw.putalpha(255)
background_img = numpy.array(background_img_raw)
background_img_float = background_img.astype(float)
foreground_img_raw = Image.open(sys.argv[2])
foreground_img_raw.putalpha(255)
foreground_img = numpy.array(foreground_img_raw)
foreground_img_float = foreground_img.astype(float)
opacity = 1.0
blended_img_float = blend_modes.difference(background_img_float, foreground_img_float, opacity)
r, g, b, a = np.transpose(blended_img_float)
alpha = np.clip((r+g+b)*2, 0, 255)
r = np.clip(r + 100, 0, 255)
g = np.clip(g + 100, 0, 255)
b = np.clip(b + 100, 0, 255)
blended_img_float = np.transpose([r, g, b, alpha])
blended_img = numpy.uint8(blended_img_float)
blended_img_raw = Image.fromarray(blended_img)
blended_img_raw.save(sys.argv[3])
```

The result looks like this

[image].

Any suggestions?

Edit: Fiddling around in Paint.net, you can get pretty close if you do the following:

1. Blend->Difference the layers
2. Use [Grim Color Reaper](https://forums.getpaint.net/topic/15595-grim-color-reaper-plugin/) on Black
3. Max the brightness and min the contrast
4. Hue shift a little, max out the saturation, and increase the lightness

It's a ton of transforms, but the result is much closer than what I've come up with programmatically. Whatever Grim Color Reaper is doing appears to be closer to correct than what I'm doing. Here's the result:

[image]

This doesn't solve the issue, unfortunately, as I need this done repeatedly, but it gives me hope that it is somehow solvable.

Edit 2: Please see this post for an example of what I'm trying to accomplish: https://community.home-assistant.io/t/floorplan-with-many-lights-in-one-area-say-hello-to-transparent-png-files/90006/8

Edit 3: I need to move on from this problem for now, but I think rather than trying to work so hard to make the proper image, I figured out a workaround on the CSS side to allow the blending to happen closer to what's appropriate. Now I just use the difference between the images like this:

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
import sys

def create_mask(foreground_filename, background_filename, output_filename):
    foreground = cv2.imread(foreground_filename)
    background = cv2.imread(background_filename)
    diff = foreground - background
    diff = cv2.cvtColor(diff, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    out_pil_image = Image.fromarray(diff)
    out_pil_image.save(output_filename)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    create_mask(sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2], sys.argv[3])
```

And the results look like this: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/agBqXr

Which is good enough for me for now. I would love to know the proper answer to this question if anyone figures it out!

Answer (score 1):

I do not know Opecv that well, but in ImageMagick, I would do the following:

base:

[image]

light:

[image]

```
convert base.png light.png -compose minus -composite minus.png
```

[image]

```
convert base.png minus.png -compose plus -composite result.png
```

[image]

ADDITION:

Here is an alternate method that compose a colored and transparent image over the original. But you will have to tweak the colors a bit. I measured a bright yellow point in the base image.

```
1) turn the minus image into gray by desaturating it. The stretch the dynamic range, then apply a gamma adjustment.

2) create a look-up table between black and that yellow color and apply it to the gray image with -clut

3) put the gray image into the alpha channel of the colorized image

4) composite the previous image over the base image


convert minus.png -modulate 100,0,100 -auto-level -gamma 1.5 minus_gray.png
convert minus_gray.png \( xc:black xc:"rgb(251,220,120)" +append \) -clut minus_color.png
convert minus_color.png minus_gray.png -alpha off -compose copy_opacity -composite alpha.png
convert base.png alpha.png -compose over -composite result3.png
```

Here are the results of the steps:

Gray:

[image]

Colorized gray:

[image]

Transparent:

[image]

Result:

[image]

ADDITION2:

```
convert light.png -alpha copy -channel a -evaluate multiply 2 +channel alpha.png
convert base.png alpha.png -compose over -composite result3.png
```

Alpha:

[image]

Result:

[image]

Comment: The issue is that I can't use a non-alpha image to build the final composite. So a simple subtraction won't do. The image you have that has a black background would need to be mostly alpha as I can't blend it back in on-the-fly (I have to leverage how alpha is treated on webpages basically).

Comment: Alpha does not support color. So there is no way to get the yellow into an alpha channel. Do I misunderstand what you mean by alpha and how you expect to use it? You can convert black to transparency and then do the -compose over -composite, but my attempt looks more orange than yellow.

Comment: I believe the issue I'm having comes down to how to "convert black to transparency" in such a way as to when I overlay the result on the base image, it reproduces the `light` image. 
If you know a way to remove the black, I'd be happy to try it!

Comment: The problem is that your difference image was created by a subtraction and will not produce the same result by compositing over the base image as it would when adding it back. Add and subtract are complementary. Over and subtract are not.

Comment: See my ADDITION to my answer.

Comment: This looks great - I'm going to try to apply it to some more images. I'm not entirely sure the hard coded color will work in general, but I think I could measure that from the average of the minus image's hue and then a 128/128 saturation and lightness.

The thing I find so perplexing about this problem is that the alpha blending is a simple function - there should be a simple way to generate `B` such that `F(A, B)=C` where `F` is the alpha blend operation, `A` is the base image, `C` is the result, and `B` is the target. We shouldn't have to hack it into existence.

Comment: I wonder if this is the equation for typical alpha blending and I could just solve for Ca: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_compositing

Comment: Why must the alpha be compositing over the base? What was wrong with just using my compose plus. Does OpenCV not have that type of  composite?

Comment: See my ADDITION2. Not perfect. But close. You can adjust the factor of 2 and see if you can get closer.

Answer (score 0):

This is a Pure PIL answer for your question.

To get the difference between the two images:-

```
from PIL import Image, ImageChops, ImageEnhance

img1 = Image.open(r"base.png")
img2 = Image.open(r"light.png")

diff = ImageChops.difference(img2, img1)
```

`ImageChops.difference()` takes in two Image objects as arguments, and returns the absolute value of the pixel-by-pixel difference between the two. In short, It calculates the **difference between the two images**.

**OUTPUT of `diff.show()`:-**

[image]

Now, since we have now obtained the difference points of both the images, We can now create a composite image out of the **diff** image and the original **base** image

Adding this line of code to the previous code:-

```
overlaid_img1 = Image.blend(img1, diff, 0.5)
```

`Image.blend()` takes as argument two image objects and a threshold, and creates a new image by interpolating between two input images, using a constant alpha(threshold argument). The output is guided by the formula:-

> image1 * (1.0 - alpha) + image2 * alpha

Where image1 & image2 are image objects, and alpha is threshold. Since we are using `0.5` as the threshold value, the formula changes to:-

> (image1 * 0.5) + (image2 * 0.5)

This means that we are taking half the color value of image1 (base) and half of image2 (diff). Since, the difference image (diff) contained mostly black pixels, due to this our base image's color pixels brightness value get's halved (or became darker then before).

**OUTPUT of `overlaid_img1.show()`:-**

[image]

Now, In order for the base image's pixels to obtain original brightness values, we need to double the brightness in the output image obtained by `Image.blend()`.

Adding this line to the original code:-

```
bright_overlay_img1 = ImageEnhance.Brightness(overlaid_img1).enhance(2.0)
```

`ImageEnhance.Brightness()` is a class used to adjust brightness of an image. `ImageEnhance.Brightness.enhance()` is the function used to do so.

what `enhance(2.0)` did, is that it doubled the brightness value of each pixel, in `overlaid_img1` image object.

**OUTPUT of `bright_overlay_img1.show()`:-**

[image]

**P.S.:-** The original code, is produced by adding all the provided code in the answer. I segmented the original code, so that I could explain the working of each function and the reasoning behind it. So for the full working, just append the each code provided in the answer.

**EDIT:-**

Just saw your comments on the answer of @fmw42, it turns out that your requirement is different then the question you asked.

From what I understood is that, you want the `diff` (the image storing the difference of both images) in a format which supports alpha (transparency), rather then a completely black Image.

For that use this code:-

```
# This is the full code

from PIL import Image, ImageChops, ImageEnhance

img1 = Image.open(r"base.png")
img2 = Image.open(r"light.png")

diff = ImageChops.difference(img2, img1).convert("RGBA")

pixels = diff.load()

for x in range(diff.size[0]):
    for y in range(diff.size[1]):
        if pixels[x, y] == (0, 0, 0, 255):
            pixels[x, y] = (0, 0, 0, 0)

diff.save("alpha_difference.png")   # saving the difference image (having alpha channel)

overlaid_img1 = Image.blend(img1.convert("RGBA"), diff, 0.5)

bright_overlay_img1 = ImageEnhance.Brightness(overlaid_img1).enhance(2.0).convert("RGB")
```

What the above code does differently from the one i mentioned before, is it converts the difference image `diff` into an alpha channel image, where it will turn a pixel transparent if it will have a completely black color (a having no difference from the original image).

**difference image (having alpha channel):-**

[image]

The outputs of both the snippets of code will still be the same.

**P.S.:-** I would recommend you to change the title/description of the question and state your problem explicitly there.

Comment: I think your approach is good, but I still think maybe there's a misunderstanding of what the result should be. As an example, this result could look something like this: https://i.imgur.com/jLk5iUh.png but such that when it is overlayed on the base image, it produces the light image.

Maybe to illustrate the point, consider that you might have two different `light` images where you need to produce two alpha background images that can both be placed on top of the original to get the merge of two (i.e. this https://i.imgur.com/jIS8zwE.png). So all the non-alpha black in the image is bad.

Comment: @user986122 I don't think you saw the edited version of my answer. Let me explain that to you, the edited version of my answer contains a snippet of code, which does the same stuff that the previous code does, the only different thing it does, is it uses `diff` (difference b/w the two images) in alpha (the case you wanted it to be). Then it overlays that alpha image over the `base` image, to get the desired output. I don't think you realized that the loops in the above code turn the black image (of mode RGB) into a RGBA image, to incorporate transparency.

Comment: @user986122 I have added a new line in my edited code, which will save the difference image under the name `alpha_difference.png` so that you can further view it. Secondly, all the non alpha black in the image, is dealt with the function `enhance()` in my original answer.

Comment: @user986122 And if by **Non alpha black** you are referring to black sections of the alpha image (black section which are still visible in it), then those are also dealt with in my code, when i convert it all to to RGB in the final image via `convert("RGB")`

Comment: I apologize, I have read your edit, but I don't understand how it solves the issue. As an example, I ran your code and used the result and it looks like this: https://i.imgur.com/RLPg6YJ.png

See how the sections that still contain high alpha values as well as shades of black cover up the background image?

Comment: @user986122 Did you copied the code and changed the variable properly? Coz the output of the above code is in the section **OUTPUT of bright_overlay_img1.show()** and as you can see the output is completely different then what you posted, give a pic of the code that you tried so that i can rectify it. ^_^

Comment: I was under the impression that the OP wanted to combine the alpha with the original by compositing it over, not by blending. If not, then my original solution using compose plus does and exact job.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer from @Vasu Deo.S is so close...

Just use the grayscale value for the alpha channel, instead of truncating at `255`.

[image]

```py
from typing import Union

from PIL import Image, ImageChops, ImageOps


def subtract_to_alpha(img: Union[str, Image.Image], base: Union[str, Image.Image]) -> Image.Image:
    if type(img) is str:
        img = Image.open(img)
    if type(base) is str:
        base = Image.open(base)

    img = img.convert("RGBA")
    base = base.convert("RGBA")

    diff = ImageChops.subtract(img, base)
    grayscale: Image.Image = ImageOps.grayscale(diff)

    
    diff.putalpha(grayscale)
    # .putalpha is equivelent to the opearation below but way efficient.
    # for x in range(diff.size[0]):
    #    for y in range(diff.size[1]):
    #        r, g, b, a = diff.getpixel((x, y))
    #        # Get the alpha channel from the grayscale
    #        alpha = grayscale.getpixel((x, y))
    #        diff.putpixel((x, y), (r, g, b, alpha))

    return diff


if __name__ == '__main__':
    subtract_to_alpha(
        'tests/data/light.png',
        'tests/data/base.png',
    ).show()
```

Edit: use `.putalpha()`